# Controls within grid column don't respect size of column

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, layout, windows-phone-8.1

So, I have a Windows Phone 8.1 application (Windows Store style) and I'm trying to make a simple 3 column layout. I'm running into the problem though that the controls I put in the smaller columns of the grid do not respect the width of the column. The control instead will be some (I assume) default size that is way too big, unless I manually specify in pixels how wide I want the control to be. I don't want to specify pixels though, since I want this to easily work on different screen sizes.

My XAML code:

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.70*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width ="0.15*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Global User Interface" FontSize="40" Width="auto"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="B" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="576" Width="Auto"  TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="206"  />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="C" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Global User Interface" FontSize="40" Height="640" Width="auto"/>
    </Grid>
```

Screenshot showing the overflowing "C" button going beyond the column line of the grid

[image]

Funny enough, taking this EXACT same XAML code and putting it in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application results in it working as I'd expect with the controls being fit to the grid

edit: Actually, even setting widths in pixels has no effect... uhh wat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `MinWidth="0"` on each of your buttons.

Comment: Wow, I've been struggling with this literally all day, thinking I had to define some custom control template or something, and this completely fixes it. thanks!